# How to ad local currency symbol - ios in app purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

How can I add the local cyrrency symbol to the Buy-Button from
https://github.com/ebutterfly/EBPurchase

```
[buyButton setTitle:[@"Buy Game Levels Pack " stringByAppendingString:productPrice] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code like the following will work:

```
SKProduct *product = ebp.validProduct; // epb is the EBPurchase object
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
NSString *formattedPrice = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

`formattedPrice` will have the appropriate currency formatting.

You should also use the `localizedTitle` and `localizedDescription` from `product` for the product's title and description. This is all obtained from the data you setup in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your quick help. I'm a newbie. Please can you explain how to  localizedTitle and localizedDescription?